# Border on bottom of UL with floating LI's without setting a height

Tags: css

I setup a jsFiddle to show what I'm doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/UfzCS/

Basically the border I set (needs to go all the way across) on the UL is showing up over (instead of under) the LI's because the LI's are floated left.  Is there any workaround for this?  I know I can set a height, but I may make the text a variable size so the height may dynamically change.

Comment: add overflow:hidden to .product-tabs ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LI are floated, so the UL does not know where to wrap them.

An easy way to fix this is to make the UL `float: left` or add a `overflow: hidden` to it.

Comment: Fantastic, overflow: hidden fixed it!